# How can I sign an application packaged by OCRA and Inno Setup?

Tags: ruby, inno-setup, ocra

I am using the following command to have OCRA build an installer using Inno Setup:

```
ocra bin/rails . --output fvc.exe 
                 --add-all-core 
                 --gemfile Gemfile 
                 --no-dep-run 
                 --gem-full 
                 --chdir-first 
                 --no-lzma 
                 --innosetup fvc.iss 
                 -- runner -e production fvc.rb
```

I would like to sign the installer package, which can be done in Inno Setup's script editor, or on the command line.  This is probably as simple as getting some arguments to the compiler, but I can't find documentation about how to do that through OCRA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [sign tool](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setup_signtool) has indeed be defined in Inno Setup IDE or on `iscc.exe` command-line.

OCRA [does not allow customization of `iscc.exe` command-line](https://github.com/larsch/ocra/blob/2e7c88fd6ac7ae5f881d838dedd7ad437bda018b/bin/ocra#L1089).

If you cannot define the sign tool in IDE (e.g. because the build script has to be standalone), you have to cheat a bit:

- Automatically import the sign tool configuration to registry before running the build (or as part of the build).

  ```
  [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Jordan Russell\Inno Setup\SignTools]
  "SignTool0"="sign=..."
  ```
- Put `iscc.bat` wrapper to `PATH` instead of `iscc.exe` and make it run `iscc.exe` with all its parameters and the sign tool configuration:

  ```
  iscc.exe %* /ssign=...
  ```